# How to get session variable from other site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem that i could not solve, How I can get a session variable from an external website?

something like: myvariable=session["othersite"];

Comment: You can't get session variables from external site unless you control that external site and many other conditions are satisfied. If you specify more details someone here will be able to give a more concrete answer.

Comment: Can you explain more, what are you trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

You have to make web request on server side, that will access external site, and external site has to have endpoint (web service) that will provide it. Also if the session variable value is sensitive, you may want to use symmetric encryption along the way.